Issue accessing AWS Cloudfront deep web links from React Expo app
I'm a NEWBIE on AWS. I have developed a React app using Expo.  It builds and works fine.  I have a few screens where I'm using weblinks to point to deep links on my companion website. (i.e., www.someurl.com?test=123)  It works fine linking to base url (www.someurl.com)  Also works fine locally.  The only difference is that my production website is running on AWS Cloudfront with S3. Note - this Next js application was setup on AWS by someone else.  Also note that all works well when I attempt to access URL directly through the browser.  So this seems specific to app weblinking.  What am I missing?  I've searched and cannot find any reference to this problem.
I've created a weblink to make a specific link to web site.
Here's the button action.
  const navigateToDonationWebview = () => {
    const webUrl = `${process.env.WEB_BASE_URL}/give&stuff?Id=${item.Identifier}`
    const webTitle = `Test thing`
    navigation.navigate('WebviewScreen', { url: webUrl, title: webTitle })
  }
here's the weblink code
`<WebView
        source={{ uri: url }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        onLoad={() => log(`WebView loaded - URL: ${url}`)}
        onError={(error) => log(`WebView error at URL: ${url} - ${error.message}`)}
      />

Looking ay my backend (Spring boot) server's log, it looks like a request to just the base url; which matches what I'm seeing.  No reference to the rest of the request or query so my Cloudfront app (or something) is stripping the query string.
Any ideas?

I assume CloudFront isn't just being used for your front-end React code, but it is also in front of your back-end Spring Boot app? If so, you probably have CloudFront configured to ignore query string parameters, so those aren't making it past the CDN cache, down to the backend. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

That's correct.  It's housing my next js front-end code.  I'll take a look... thanks!
